# Is it necessary to have two coordinates for the public key of ECDSA?

Tags: c, cryptography, ecdsa, ecdh

I am trying to generate an ECDSA key-pair using an external library called [easy-ecc](https://github.com/jestan/easy-ecc). The thing that I do not understand is this library generates a single coordinate for public key. As far as I see from books, online ECDSA generators or NIST test vectors, the public key has always two coordinates on the curve (X and Y). For example, if `P-384 curve` is used, the length of the private key will be 48 bytes and the public key will have two different points X and Y, `48 bytes` each. So, in total `96 bytes`. Yet, the `ecc_make_key` function does not behave as expected.

Here is the prototype of the function that creates key pairs:

```c
int ecc_make_key(
    uint8_t p_publicKey[ECC_BYTES+1],
    uint8_t p_privateKey[ECC_BYTES]
);
```

This function fills the empty arrays with pass by reference strategy. However, why the `p_publicKey` has to be `ECC_BYTES+1` instead of `ECC_BYTES*2`?

Comment: Presumably the public key is specified in compressed format. A public key `(x,y)` can be specified in uncompressed format (`0x04|x|y`) or in compressed format (`b|x`, where `b` is `0x02` for even `y` and `0x03` for odd `y`), see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/56442).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/jestan/easy-ecc/blob/master/ecc.c#L1064);

```c
int ecc_make_key(uint8_t p_publicKey[ECC_BYTES+1], uint8_t p_privateKey[ECC_BYTES])
```

takes two parameters a public key and a private key and initialize, them.

Let's look at the last three lines;

```c
    ecc_native2bytes(p_privateKey, l_private);
    ecc_native2bytes(p_publicKey + 1, l_public.x);
    p_publicKey[0] = 2 + (l_public.y[0] & 0x01);
```

- private key just copied and that is just a big integer.
- Only the x coordinate of the public point is copied. This clearly indicates [point compression](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83468/18298) and that need an indicator to resolve the `y` from only `x` since except order two points, all other points have a negative.

  - `0x04` indicated there is no compression so the public point is stored completely as

    `0x04|public_x|public_y`
  - `0x02` This indicates that the `public_y` is even, and
  - `0x03` This indicates that the `public_y` is odd

    Both is stored as `(0x02|0x03)|public_x`

**Why do we compress**

1. It requires fewer data to store and transmit
2. It helps on [point validation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89353/18298)